# Conditional callbacks scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, conditional-statements

I have in my model some conditional callbacks

```
before_create :save_tempfile, :if => :has_stream_content?
after_create :add_track, :if => :has_stream_content?
before_update :add_track, :if => :has_stream_content?
```

Is there a rails way to organize a conditional callback scope? Smth like this:

```
before_create :save_tempfile; after_create, before_update :add_track, :if => :has_stream_content?
```

Answer (score 1):

*Nope, there is not.*

By the way your code looks fine to me as it is. Way more readable than the version without the new lines.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, you cannot have something as you are looking for. You can have multiple conditions for a callback using `proc` but not single condition for multiple callback. The current code is the only way to achieve this. For better understanding and more clear picture, Refer this

[Callbacks overview](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html): Active Record provides hooks into this object life cycle so that you can control your application and its data.